# Having trouble in embedded post in Joomla 3.3.6

Tags: iframe, joomla, embed, joomla3.0

I'm having a problem in including embedded post in a Joomla! article. I'm using the TinyMCE editor.

Steps I have followed :

1. In Text Filter Settings for Super User - *No filtering*
2. In TinyMCE settings - remove *script* and *Iframe* tag from "Prohibited Elements".

I'm not able to add Pinterest code:

```
<a data-pin-do="embedPin" data-pin-width="medium" href="https://uk.pinterest.com/pin/dfg/"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the code is getting stripped out because the link is not wrapped around any text. You could possibly add `&nbsp;` inside the link. However, I would suggest using the "None" editor when adding embed code to your posts. I use [Switch Editor](http://anything-digital.com/community-products/editor-switcher-the-convenient-and-free-editor-selector.html) to quickly change editors.

1. Switch to "None"
2. Add the embed code
3. Save the article
4. Switch back to your favorite WYSIWYG editor to edit other articles